# If and else not working, incorrect output

Tags: python, if-statement

It should only accept when the input is y or yes case insensitive. If any other else, it should end the program and print "Bye! Good game!".

However, when I run the program and I enter "y" or "yes" or any letter, the program still runs.

Also, I am not sure where to properly enter the `casefold()` so I placed it twice.

```
continue_game = input("Try another game: Yes/No: ").casefold()
    
if (continue_game == 'y' or continue_game == "yes").casefold():
    print(continue_game)
    continue

else:
    continue_game != 'y'
    print("Bye! good game!")
```

Comment: `continue_game != 'y'` has no effect whatsoever. I'm not sure what you intended to achieve by this expression.

Comment: Did you try running this code before including it in your question?  It should immediately raise an error, something like `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'casefold'`.

Comment: `"so I placed it twice"` <== never a strategy that a computer programmer should employ.

Comment: But surely your program *does* print `"Bye! good game!"` when you enter some other letter?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
continue_game = input("Try another game: Yes/No: ").casefold()
# assuming this next part is in a loop of sorts

while <insert condition here>:
    if continue_game in ("y", "yes"):
       print(continue_game)
    else:
       print("Bye! good game!")
       break
```

In order for `break` to work, the second part of the code **must** be in a loop. Also, you don't need the `continue` clause, unless you were planning on having code after your `else` block that you didn't want to execute.

Comment: could `casefold` what's returned by `input` and save one call that way, also then `if continue_game in ("y", "yes"):`

Comment: But good intuition on spotting that `break` is needed.

Comment: @Matiiss correct, you could do that

Answer (score 2):

You should put your code in an "infinite" while loop, you can achieve that by using "True". Your loop will run until you cut off it with the "break". You should only use the casefold() after the input.

```py
while True:
    continue_game = input("Try another game: Yes/No: ").casefold()
    if (continue_game == 'y' or continue_game == "yes"):
        print(continue_game)
        
    else:
        print("Bye! good game!")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression:

```
(continue_game == 'y' or continue_game == "yes").casefold()
```

should raise an `AttributeError`, because the expression `(continue_game == 'y' or continue_game == "yes")` is a `bool`, and a `bool` doesn't have a `casefold` method.

The idea of `casefold()` is that you apply it to the two strings you're comparing in order to make the comparison case-sensitive.  So you'd use it like:

```
continue_game = input("Try another game: Yes/No: ").casefold()
    
if continue_game == 'y'.casefold() or continue_game == "yes".casefold():
    ...
```

Since the strings you're comparing against are hard-coded lowercase strings, though, you don't really need to casefold them.  I'd suggest just explicitly `lower`ing the `continue_game` input:

```
continue_game = input("Try another game: Yes/No: ").lower()

if continue_game == 'y' or continue_game == "yes":
    ...
```

or simpler yet:

```
continue_game = input("Try another game: Yes/No: ").lower()

if continue_game in ('y', 'yes'):
    ...
```

or even just looking at the first letter (so you accept anything starting with "y", like `yes` or `yeah` or `yup`):

```
continue_game = input("Try another game: Yes/No: ").lower()

if continue_game.startswith('y'):
    ...
```

Moving further along in the code -- the problem with your `if/else` is that (assuming you have this in a loop that doesn't terminate by some other means) a loop will continue if you don't do anything to break it.  So the `continue` is pointless, because the loop was going to continue anyway -- and after you print `Bye!`, the loop does exactly that.

What you want to do instead is `break` the loop when you want it to stop:

```
continue_game = input("Try another game: Yes/No: ").lower()

if continue_game.startswith('y'):
    print(continue_game)
else:
    print("Bye! good game!")
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this for you, if you like something simple, fast, no loop (loop is not needed in this case except you want to ask for the input again or you can replace print with a call to main function of the game).
This will `print(continue_game)` when input is yes, YES, YeS, YEs, Y or y. And will `print("Bye! good game!")` when the input is NO, No, nO, N, n, or any other input beyond "Yes" :)

```
continue_game = input("Try another game: Yes/No: ")
print(continue_game) if continue_game.lower() in ('y', 'yes') else print("Bye! good game!")
```

But if you want to revalidate user input other than 'Yes' or 'No', you might need a loop and also a counter to avoid infinite loop.

```
counter = 3  # Change this counter as you like
for counts in range(counter):
    continue_game = input(f"[{counts+1}/{counter}] Try another game: Yes/No: ").casefold()
    if continue_game in ('y', 'yes'):
        print(continue_game)
        break
    elif continue_game in ('n', 'no'):
        print("Bye! good game!")
        break
    else:
        if counts + 1 == counter: print("Bye! good game!")
```

This will ask the user when the input is other than 'Yes' or 'No', and it will end the loop after certain amount of attemps (`counter`) when it did not receive expected input from the user (Assuming 'No' for the input).

```
[1/3] Try another game: Yes/No: what?
[2/3] Try another game: Yes/No: wait
[3/3] Try another game: Yes/No: 2 minutes
Bye! good game!
```